# Library Sigslot can not use in my project

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I am developing on the operating system Ubuntu. I need to use a library Sigslot (https://github.com/palacaze/sigslot/tree/master) in my project.
I connect it to my project via Conan - https://conan.io/center/recipes/sigslot. I wrote in CMakeLists.txt the following lines indicated in Conan:

```
find_package(PalSigSlot REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(MyProject Pal::PalSigSlot ${X11_LIBRARIES} )
```

but I get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPalSigSlot.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "PalSigSlot", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PalSigSlot" with
  any of the following names:

    PalSigSlotConfig.cmake
    palsigslot-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PalSigSlot" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "PalSigSlot_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "PalSigSlot" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Documented name of the package is `PalSigslot`, with the second `s` in **lowercase**.

Comment: I found a solution. I just don't write anything in the file CMakeLists.txt and the library sigslot works successfully in code.